# XMLHTTP Request bad respondheader

Tags: javascript, api, curl, request

I'm trying to request an api to get a token.
The token is in the RespondHeader, but my code doesn't find it. But I get it with curl so it's sure that I'm missing something.
Can you help me ?

this is curl:
`curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8080/login -d '{"username":"poulet", "password":"poulet"}'`

And this is what I get

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJwb3VsZXQiLCJleHAiOjE1NTEzMDUxNDJ9.NTKyMKEKTnRDU-TzcG6WlNYVCjgQ91vBgK4SbTFECenRH_GCllxA-dPogx3RQ0XH0eCwH7LpCU8Ttyxb2idl_Q
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 26 Feb 2019 22:05:42 GMT
```

Now this is my Javascript code

```
const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/login', true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.getAllResponseHeaders());
        console.log(this.getResponseHeader("Authorization"));
    }
};
console.log(req);
req.send(JSON.stringify({username : "poulet", password : "poulet"}));
```

and this is what i get

> cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
>   expires: 0  pragma: no-cache
>
> null

Thank you in advance.

Comment: add `console.log(this.readyState, this.status);` in your callback function  to validate it has been invoked.

Comment: Where are you running this; Node or browser? If browser, what is the URL of the page? If it's not on `http://127.0.0.1:8080`, does your API supports CORS? Are there any errors reported?

Comment: I'm running the app in a browser and the url is 127.0.0.1:8081, I don't know if the api support CORS :/

Comment: ok problem solve it was problem with CORS in the serv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if people have the same probleme. It was the server, it didn't have cross-origin, and so some headers where missing.

I solve it by additing

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try to replace **this**

`console.log(this.getResponseHeader("Authorization"));`

with **req**

`console.log(req.getResponseHeader("Authorization"));`

Comment: same thing, the result is null